Why can completeness on $\mathbb{R}$ be defined in terms of lower bounds as well as upper bounds?
The original exercise was this: Show that the Completeness Property for the real number system could equally well have been defined by the statement, “Any nonempty set of reals that has a lower bound has a greatest lower bound.”
What I have tried:
Bounds are symmetric notions
These are diagrams I made to try to understand the relationships of components, but I wonder what are the underlying patterns that make this in $\mathbb{R}$:

Commutative diagram with components as arrows
Commutative diagram with isomorphisms
In these diagrams it doesn't matter to what node we connect the domain, because the middle part commutes. It is as if the middle part was a single node, all the nodes and arrows are the same for the input.
I believe this is because lower bound and upper bound are symmetric notions. Flipping the ≤ sign in their definitions maps one to the other. Does this mean they are isomorphic? I think so. They are invertible, by flipping the sign we get one from the other.
The definitions of infimum and supremum have a similar (the same?) relationship.
Something that seems very interesting, is that if we have lower bounds, upper bounds, infimum and supremum as isomorphic arrows in a category there seem to be isomorphic functors mapping one to the other. There are similar functors between supremum and infimum, and there are natural transformations mapping these, and so on. Perhaps this is not the case, I'm a novice at this stuff, but my brain branches of into everywhich-way with these patterns.
Update:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S\subseteq\mathbb{R},S\neq\varnothing@>>>S\ \text{has bound in}\ \mathbb{R}@=\mathbb{R}\ \text{is complete}
\end{CD}
\begin{CD}
s@>>>c
\end{CD}
$\mathbb{R}$ under addition is a monoid, and a group with one object $\bullet$, where every morphism has a reverse morphism
$\forall r \in \mathbb{R}\ \exists f_r: \bullet \longrightarrow \bullet$
$\forall f_r\ \exists f_{-r}\ [f_r \circ f_{-r} = id]$
This pattern of reverse morphisms seems to be the same as the reverse morphisms of l and u. And I think this entire diagram
Diagram of more general relationships
has this structure of one object $\bullet$, where every morphism has a reverse morphism, so for the input s all the nodes and arrows look the same, and the output is c, or completeness.

Okay, trying to use category theory for this seems like overkill, which makes me think I must be missing something.
To be clear, you are trying to show that $\mathbb{R}$ being complete (as a metric space) is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ having the property that all subsets with a lower bound have an infimum? And, as otherwise this equivalence would be trivially true, I assume the only thing we're allowed to presuppose is that $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field?

Your diagrams doesn't help because you're not using the order of the field. The important property here is that if $a<b$ then $(-1)\times a > (-1)\times b$, which leads to the needed step to go from $\sup$ to $\inf$ and viceversa: $\sup (-S) = - \inf(S)$

@jjagmath This is an answer to the question, not a comment. As such, it should be posted as an answer by the rules of this site. See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

@MartinBrandenburg There are a lot of gaps to fill to turn this in an actual proof. I'd say it's a hint.

@jjagmath Is this the same property that creates negative numbers? Similar to that of $\mathbb{Z}$? I still struggle to see these structures. What is the simplest structure that this pattern works in, a total order? Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ have this structure.

@kabelabel Thank you for your comment, I must learn what metric space and field are. Abstracting away aspects that are relevant to the question seems to illuminate the underlying patterns. Category theory seems to do this job well, and I am also focusing on learning it, but I am also interested in other approaches to understanding this question. The patterns you find can be generalised to other contexts also. I don't yet see clearly how $\mathbb{R}$ is structured that makes this pattern possible.

I think the category theory here is actually cluttering your ideas, instead of clarifying them. Remember that category theory is at its best when it's showing how multiple seemingly different ideas are all related to each other. It can be less useful when trying to prove a single fact about a single object (as in this problem). Category theory is an extremely useful tool, but it's important to have more than one tool at your disposal. A huge part of becoming a mathematician is developing a sensitivity for which tool is right for which job. See, for instance, this excellent blog post by Terry Tao.
Moving on, some real work is done to show that metric completeness is equivalent to the existence of upper bounds, and it seems like your course/book/etc has done that work. You could just redo the proof you were shown, using lower bounds instead of upper bounds everywhere in sight, but I appreciate the instinct to look for something simpler.
One nice option, discussed by @jjagmath in the comments, is to notice that $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded above if and only if $-S = \{-x \mid x \in S\}$ is bounded below. It's not hard to show that $\sup(S) = - \inf (-S)$, so that having all lower bounds is equivalent to having all upper bounds and thus to metric completeness.
But it sounds like you really want to use category theory in some capacity, so here's another option which is true for all lattices (read: all thin categories with finite limits and finite colimits):
Say that you know $L$ is a lattice with all lower bounds, and say you have a set $S \subseteq L$ which is bounded above. We want to define $\sup(S)$ somehow, but all we have access to is lower bounds... Well, why don't we look at $\inf(\{\text{upper bounds for $S$}\})$? That is, $\inf(\{ x \mid \forall s \in S . x \geq s \})$? It turns out that one can show $\sup(S) = \inf(\{\text{upper bounds for $S$}\})$ (see here, say), and of course we can define $\inf(S)$ as $\sup(\{\text{lower bounds for $S$}\})$ and so having all lower bounds is equivalent to having all upper bounds again.
This doesn't look category theoretic the way I stated it, but we've shown that for poset categories, completeness is equivalent to cocompleteness! Poset categories are "small" as far as categories go, and this theorem is a special case of the fact that accessible categories are complete if and only if they're cocomplete. Here an "accessible category" should also be thought of as "small" in an informal sense (not to be confused with the technical concept of a small category!) and indeed for accessible categories completeness and cocompleteness are equivalent!
In fact, the proof for accessible categories is basically the same too, but you have to meditate a bit on what accessible categories are and how the adjoint functor theorems work to see it.

I hope this helps ^_^

Thank you Chris! Your answer helps a lot. The exercise is part of a course on mathematical thinking and this question is one of the questions introducing analysis. It turned out to be a fun exercise in finding a pattern in a set that can be generalised to other contexts. By thinking about these patterns and constructing diagrams I gained a lot of insight, for example that arguments are something like circuits. The pattern of supremums being infimums is very interesting, I actually noticed this already and was very happy about it! I will ponder the concepts you shared.

If you pick a set of real numbers with a bound, you picked another, complementary set with a bound along with it:

The resulting diagram is more like this:
$$\begin{CD}
\exists \inf(S) \in \mathbb{R} @<\Leftarrow<< \exists l(S) \in \mathbb{R} @<<< \forall S \in \mathbb{R}, S \neq \varnothing @>>> \exists u(S) \in \mathbb{R} @>\Rightarrow>> \exists \sup(S) \in \mathbb{R} \\
@| @| @| @| @| \\
\exists \sup(\bar{S}) \in \mathbb{R} @<<\Leftarrow< \exists u(\bar{S}) \in \mathbb{R} @<<< \forall \bar{S} \in \mathbb{R}, \bar{S} \neq \varnothing @>>> \exists l(\bar{S}) \in \mathbb{R} @>>\Rightarrow> \exists \inf(\bar{S}) \in \mathbb{R} 
\end{CD}$$
